# Need help with modelling a helmet

Tags: modeling, topology

Blender File: https://drive.google.com/file/d/14Y9j3ABEq0XOu63Fr3aPSiCehDvm49Cu/view?usp=sharing

I need help with starting this model. Below is my situation and current approach. Would be grateful to anyone who helps!
[image: h]

[image]:

Comment: Hello,and welcome!  Please do not use all caps as it is considered yelling. Also, text inside of images is generally not good, as it is not searchable. Please write out your entire question outside of your images. Lastly, please use [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) for uploading blend files in the future. Thanks!

Comment: Forgive my ignorance. I'll be sure to do this on future posts!

Comment: You can edit your post using the [edit button](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/187506/edit)... Also please make your title specific, this site is no regular forum, it's a Q&A site. How this site works: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour. Please read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: so u can use sculpting for making a helmet

Answer (score 2):

I suggest not to start from a sphere, but from a cube (apply a subdivision modifier of 2 or 3).

The box/sphere is better cause you can have better loops:

[image]